# Why do I have to declare var = Class.new?

Tags: ruby

Why can I not just set `var = Class?` Why does it have to be `var = Class.new?` You can set variables in arrays, hashes, strings with just `var = [], {},` or `"some_string"`. Is Class doing something specific that makes it different?

```
class Word
    def palindrome(string)
        string == string.reverse
    end
end

w = Word.new

puts w.palindrome("racecar")
```

Comment: I think `w = Word` just sets `w` to be a reference to the class, not an instance of the class.

Comment: Initialization/instantiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you’ve got the special case backwards:

- `[]` is shorthand for `Array.new`
- `{}` is shorthand for `Hash.new`
- `""` is shorthand for `String.new` (sort of, since there’s no way to specify a string without a syntactic structure (e.g. `"`, `'`, or `%`).

You *can* do `var = Klass`, but that assigns `var` to `Klass`, whereas `Klass.new` calls the `new` method on the object `Klass` (just like any other method call, nothing special at all), which returns a new *instance* of the class `Klass`.

<sub>Note: I’ve replaced `Class` in your question with `Klass` (defined via `class Klass; end`) to reduce confusion, as talking about `Class` and `Class` instances introduces a lot of meta-ness that I don’t think you’re concerned with here, and that you merely intended `Class` to represent any class.</sub>

Comment: The issue with my code is that if I remove .new then I get an error saying Word is not defined. Which doesn't make sense to me since all variables that are capitalized should only be Class variables.

Comment: @h00d13z: Class variables start with a double at sigil (`@@`), not with a capital letter. Variables that start with a capital letter are constants, not class variables.